# Splitting a Jasper Reports detail band across multiple columns

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a Jasper Reports sub report that presents as a narrow table with two fields and around 100 rows.  What I would like to do is to present the data as two two column tables side by side - 50 rows on one table and 50 rows in the other.  I have no idea how to start with this or in fact if it is possible?  Any guidance appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the properties of your report (the root in the report inspector) you will find the section 
"Columns"  change columns = **2** and if it does not adjust the column with value to 50% of your usable page size you will need to update that as well. you can also use the print order = **Horizonal** alternate between column 1&2 other wise you will need to adjust you page Height to control how many are in a column.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="report1" language="groovy" columnCount="2" printOrder="Horizontal" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="277" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="858922b0-abde-475c-b53d-12e4f5ecf6d4">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[Select Rownum col1, Rownum col2
From dual
Connect By Rownum <= 100]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="COL1" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <field name="COL2" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="65057af1-383c-464a-a49e-0c173170cee4" x="74" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[COL1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="34c22bda-1d12-4699-ae78-4b3785754b1e" x="174" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[COL2]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="4dd534f4-5d30-45dc-b9e4-f8752c0f8a9a" x="74" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COL1}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement uuid="bef22f4d-1583-4e50-b97f-30a04471e6d4" x="174" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COL2}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement uuid="770d97bb-8266-4647-a6a6-af053f474fb7" x="0" y="0" width="74" height="20"/>
                <box>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
                </box>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[row]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!  I will try the code tonight and let you know